# Curl Exec lein with Puppet on Centos Vagrant no such file or directory

Tags: clojure, centos, vagrant, puppet, leiningen

**EDIT**

This sites.pp seems to work.

```
class lein {
  $lein = "/usr/local/bin/lein"
  $url = 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/technomancy/leiningen/stable/bin/lein'

  exec { 'download lein':
    command => "/usr/bin/curl -sL -o ${lein} ${url}",
    creates => $lein,
  }

  file { $lein:
    mode => '0755',
    require => Exec['download lein'],
  }

  exec { 'install lein':
    command => $lein,
    require => File[$lein],
  }
}
```

---

I'm trying to install lein on a Centos Vagrant using Puppet.

To install lein you just run the script. I'm trying to dowload the script with curl, make it executable and then executing it but I'm getting `no such file or directory`. I have verified that the file `/usr/local/bin/lein` exists, so not sure why I'm getting the error.

So what I'm trying to accomplish is the puppet equivalent of this shell:

```
curl -sL -o /usr/local/bin/lein https://raw.githubusercontent.com/technomancy/leiningen/stable/bin/lein
chmod 0755 /usr/bin/local/lein
/usr/local/bin/lein
```

Also on a side note, is it possible to run exec as a non-privileged user?

**puppet/manifests/site.pp**

```
class lein {
  exec { 'download lein':
    command => 'curl -sL -o /usr/local/bin/lein https://raw.githubusercontent.com/technomancy/leiningen/stable/bin/lein',
    path => '/usr/bin',
  }
  file { '/usr/local/bin/lein':
    mode => '0755',
    require => Exec['download lein'],
  }
  exec { 'install lein':
    command => 'lein',
    path => '/usr/local/bin',
    require => File['/usr/local/bin/lein'],
  }
}
```

**Vagrantfile**

```
# -*- mode: ruby -*-
# vi: set ft=ruby :

Vagrant.configure(2) do |config|
  config.vm.box = "puphpet/centos65-x64"

  config.vm.provision "puppet" do |p|
    p.module_path = "puppet/modules"
    p.manifests_path = "puppet/manifests"
    p.manifest_file = "site.pp"
  end
end
```

Comment: Just scanning your question, but is this a typo in your Vagrantfile? `config.vm.box = "puphpet/centos65-x64"`

Comment: Nope, I thought the same when I copied it https://atlas.hashicorp.com/puphpet/boxes/centos65-x64

Answer (score 1):

> Also on a side note, is it possible to run exec as a non-privileged user?

Yes, you can, add the user in your block

```
class lein {
  $lein = "/usr/local/bin/lein"
  $url = 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/technomancy/leiningen/stable/bin/lein'

  exec { 'download lein':
    command => "/usr/bin/curl -sL -o ${lein} ${url}",
    creates => $lein,
    user    => "vagrant";
  }

  file { $lein:
    mode => '0755',
    require => Exec['download lein'],
  }

  exec { 'install lein':
    command => $lein,
    require => File[$lein],
    user    => "vagrant";
  }
}

include lein
```

Comment: that's awesome, but is there supposed to be a ;

Comment: right, `,` would work too, as long as the ';' is not in the middle I think puppet is fine

Answer (score 0):

On a much simpler note: have you tried piping?

```
class lein {
  $command = 'curl -sL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/technomancy/leiningen/stable/bin/lein | bash -s install'
  package { 'curl':
    ensure => 'installed',
  }
  exec { 'download lein':
    command => $command,
    path    => $::path,
    require => Package['curl'],
  }
}
```

Comment: I'll try that in the morning, but I think the file doubles as a installer and the binary for after it's installed, so it still needs to be on the file system.

Answer (score 0):

I got it to work by removing the path to both execs and using absolute paths for the commands. Also lein needs the HOME environment set or else it will try and download files to /.lein and it needs to be ran as vagrant

Successful **sites.pp**

```
class { 'jdk_oracle': }class lein {
  $lein = "/usr/local/bin/lein"
  $url = 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/technomancy/leiningen/stable/bin/lein'
  $leinhome = '/home/vagrant'

  exec { 'download lein':
    command => "/usr/bin/curl -sL -o ${lein} ${url}",
    creates => $lein,
    require => Class['jdk_oracle']
  }

  file { $lein:
    mode => '0755',
    require => Exec['download lein'],
  }

  exec { 'install lein':
    environment => ["HOME=${leinhome}"],
    command => $lein,
    require => File[$lein],
    creates => "${leinhome}/.lein/self-installs/leiningen-2.5.3-standalone.jar",
    user => 'vagrant',
  }
}

include jdk_oracle
include lein
```